# Uploaded file was empty

Tags: assets, upload

We've got all the max settings set up OK as per https://craftcms.com/support/upload-troubleshooting, but we are still getting errors. The log file just shows this, nothing more:

> 2014/10/24 11:26:35 [error] [application] Uploaded file was empty

What else should we be looking for?

Comment: Is it just a particular file, or all files? Can you enable devMode, reproduce the problem and post the stack trace leading up to the error? Also, check and see if you have a `craft/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log` file and if anything related is getting logged there.

Comment: @RussBack, did you get this straightened out? We're attempting to round up stagnant questions and would love to know if there's something to learn here.

Comment: We haven't actually. I have a ticket update from Brad to look at - will reply today if I can.

Comment: Hey guys, im actually having the same isssue, any insights you could share?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and all PHP settings were set OK. I couldn't upload a 2MB file, but uploading a 20KB file was fine.

The problem was that the `/tmp` folder was almost completely full (because PHP stores the temporary file in `/tmp` before moving it to web/user space i.e. your assets folder). Freeing up space in this folder solved the issue.